# Cant pass data to component from service. Subject's observers just dissapeared

Tags: angular, rxjs, signalr, subscribe, behaviorsubject

I want to pass data from angular Service to angular Component at the time I get "askServerResponse" call from server.
I use BehaviorSubject in that case.
While debugging obeservers at **hubconnection.on in service, inside onlineUsersSubject, my observers are empty** and noticed an error (it was not thrown) inside 'arguments' and 'caller' properties: "'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter"

However, at the moment I debug onlineUsersSubject **inside chat component, after subscribing, observers inside onlineUsersSubject are NOT empty**

**I can call onlineUsersSubject.next() method anywhere but serverListeners, and it will work fine and, I can call next() method from serverListeners on any other subject INSIDE this service and it will also work fine**

So, it seems like angular doesn't allow me to pass exactly data from sereverListeners  exactly to any component but servise itself.

signal-r.service.ts

```
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
  public onlineUsersSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("abcd");

  startConnection = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://localhost:7024/toastr', {
          skipNegotiation: true,
          transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
        })
        .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 1000, 5000])
        .build();

      this.setServerListener();

      this.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then((data) => {
          this.onlineUsersSubject.next("!!!!"); // this line do nothing in chat component
          console.log('Hub Connection Started! ' + data);
          resolve('Hub Connection Started! '+ data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('An Error occurred: ' + err);
          reject(err);
        })

    });
  }

setServerListener() {
    this.hubConnection.on("askServerResponse", (someText) => {
      //someText is not empty, i'v debugged this
      //when I debug next line, observers inside BehaviorSubject from  chat componnent dissapeared
      this.onlineUsersSubject.next(someText);
    })
```

chat.component.ts

```
import {SignalRService} from "../../signal-r.service";
export class ChatComponent {

  constructor(private signalR: SignalRService) {
    this.signalR.onlineUsersSubject.subscribe({
      next:(res) => {
        console.warn("in component:", res);//expect to warn in console, but do nothing
      },
      error:(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

it throws no error, everything works fine but the data is not passed to component...

Comment: please describe your problem and ask a specific question (not in the title). Describe what's happening, what you expect to happen and show the error Log if you got one

Comment: it's a typo or maybe the error you have: `this.signalR;.onlineUsersSubject.subscribe({`    you need to delete a semicolumn `;`

Comment: unfortunately, that was not the case

Comment: Where are you calling the startConnection method?

Comment: App component, in constructor. There are no problems with connection, I can send and receive data just fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `SignalRService` is not a Singleton.
pleas add `@Injectable`

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
```

Comment: Ty for answer, i did not paste the whole code, service and coponents work fine, except the scenario i'v metioned